# Checkbox to textview android?

Tags: android, eclipse, checkbox, textview

I want that when I click on the checkbox "a" for example, then the text view1 displays "a", I have 3 options per text view. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show us what you have already tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
      if(isChecked) {
          text_view1.setText("a");
      }
   }
};
```